# Use both bumpMap & normalMap on MeshStandardMaterial at the same time

Tags: three.js

I'm trying to apply both normal and bump maps to a single material. My normal map is static and shows larger features on the the surface while the bump map is supposed to be exchangeable to change cloth/fabric pattern.

They both work separately well but when I apply the normal map the bump map has no effect

```
var cube = new THREE.Mesh(
    new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 1),
    new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({
        normalMap: new THREE.TextureLoader().load("normal.jpg"),
        bumpMap: new THREE.TextureLoader().load("bump.jpg"),
    })
);
```

Does three.js support this?

Comment: No, you can't set a `bumpMap` and `normalMap` at the same time. [Documentation](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/materials/MeshStandardMaterial.bumpMap)

Comment: Depending on the intended usage, a [displacementMap](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/materials/MeshStandardMaterial.displacementMap) may be a suitable replacement for the `bumpMap`.

Comment: @ScieCode thanks for that, I somehow missed it in the documentation. I eventually ended up merging the maps in Photoshop. The limitation definitely complicates things :-(